# "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" adding controller to list element with list.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, listjs

I am trying to create a list object using the list.js library and to add it to the angular.js root scope in order to use it in the nested scopes. This works fine as long as I don't add a controller to the list elements.

If I do so a  I get the following error in the javascript console.

> "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"

Same happens if the list is initialised inside an init() function called with ng-init.

Here are the html and js files

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="listBug.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController" ng-app="theApp">
<div id="theList">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <div ng-controller="divController">
                <span class="id"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>      
</body>

</html>
```

listBug.js

```
var app = angular.module('theApp', [])

mainController=function($scope){

    var opts={valueNames: ['id'] }
    $scope.theList=new List('theList', opts);
}

app.controller("MainController", mainController)


divController=function($scope){

}

app.controller("divController", divController)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the DOM isn't fully loaded when your code is being called. You can delay it by doing the following

```
mainController=function($scope){
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var opts={valueNames: ['id'] } 
        $scope.theList=new List('theList', opts);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Out of curiosity I wonder why the error comes out only when adding a controller to a list element

Comment: It looks like any angular code like  {{}} or ng-click has the same effect. My guess is that Angular might be busy rewriting the DOM to insert what it needs while listjs is also trying to work with it.